# Javac for dynamic compilation is not working

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I am trying to compile a HelloWorld class just as a test and it is showing an error that I don't know how to solve. It seems like it is something about incompatible version, but when I do `java -version` and `javac -version` both display 1.8.0_73.

Here is what I am trying to compile:

```
String arquivo2 = "/C:/classes/HelloWorld.java";
PrintWriter saida = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("logCompilacao.txt"));
int resultadoCompilacao = com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(new String[]{arquivo2},saida);
```

But this is the output:

```
/C:/classes/HelloWorld.java:2: cannot access java.lang.Object
bad class file: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/Object.class)
class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 49.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
public class HelloWorld {
       ^
1 error
```

"class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 49.0". Does someone know how to solve this problem? I tried a lot but I didn't find out how to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the correct `java` and `javac` programs? You might have two different versions for one of them.

Comment: looks like your java & javac version dis-match,

Comment: @MarounMaroun Ya I am sure I am running the correct java. About the javac, I added an external jar that I downloaded in another site because without this 'javac.jar' my code would not import some libraries like com.sun.tools.javac.Main. If that is the problem, I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to solve it. It seems like by default eclipse only imports jre jars so I had to add as an external jar the file 'tools.jar' found in my jdk folder. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\lib\tools.jar`. 
After that I could compile my classes

Answer (score 0):

You added some external from another side in order be able to run the java compiler.

That is not a good approach. Most likely, you have only a JRE (runtime environment) installed.

Instead, you should download an install a JDK (development kit). The later one comes with javac; and you can be assured that its "javac" and "java" binaries will work fine together.

So: make sure you are starting with a correct environment; not something that you pulled together with stuff from here or there.

Comment: But that is the problem. JDK is installed and like I said is the latest version: 1.8.0_73. JRE and JDK are both installed. But without this external jar, the program doesn't run